# How to only read lines that contain some letters at a specific position in the line

Tags: awk

I have a file in this format:

```
Some, Text 
     sub text 1
     sub text 2
     sub text 3

Foo, Bar
   bar1
   bar2
   bar3

Shui, Wong K
       subtext1

Other Stuff
    something else
```

How can I extract only the main lines from this file such that the new file contains:

```
Some, Text
Foo, Bar
Shui, Wong K
Other Stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell awk to only print lines that start with a letter

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]/' infile
```

Output:

```
Some, Text 
Foo, Bar
Shui, Wong K
Other Stuff
```

Or the same thing with `grep`:

```
grep '^[[:alpha:]]' infile
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z]`. Or even `[[:upper:]]` if it start a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you're tying to do but here's an example

```
awk 'BEGIN{min=2;max=5}
{
 if (NR>=min)
{
if(NR<=max)
print
}
}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp matching anything but lines starting with whitespace. I think there's no need for awk, I'd use grep instead:

```
grep -e "^[^ ]"
```

In awk:

```
awk '/^[^ ]/'
```

Answer (score 0):

the followings worked here:

```
awk '/^\S/'
grep '^\S'
```

I noticed that for your example, this works too:  :)

```
awk '/,/'
```